# PHAR - use cwd instead of sys_temp_dir

Tags: php, phar

Is there a way to force an instance of PHAR to use the current working directory as a cache instead of the sys_temp_dir (/tmp)?
I realize that I can change sys_temp_dir in php.ini but that would affect other functions too and not just PHAR.

Reason - a Raspberry Pi running in read only mode (for SD card health!), but once a day, data from the Pi is archived (using PHAR) and uploaded, but due to the size of the archive, I'm running out of RAM because /tmp is loaded in tmpfs.
I would like to create a writeable partition purely for PHAR to use as a cache.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, separating the php script to run a bash script which uses tar instead of phar.
I'm still evaluating the results...